# Issue with Nativewind CSS Styles Not Displaying

Tags: typescript, react-native, npm, tailwind-css, nativewind

I created an npm package called `react-native-toastbox` for toast notifications in React Native using `nativewind`. However, after downloading from npm, the code works, but the CSS (from `nativewind`) doesn't, causing toasts not to display. I've checked for conflicts and errors in `nativewind` configuration but can't find the issue. Any insights on compatibility, conflicts, or package structure would be appreciated. Details and code are in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Slaverdure06/React-Native-Toastbox).

I tried changing the version of `Nativewind`, refactoring my component yet I still can't see it when I download my package. I may think it's a missing css config, but I can't quite figure it out.

Thanks for your help!